# run python in terminal using sublime

Tags: python, linux, terminal, sublimetext3

I use Linux Mint 17.3 and recently installed Sublime Text 3 *(unregistered version)*. In order to run python scripts in terminal *(the external terminal of the OS, not the internal one of the IDE)* I fount somewhere this:

Tools -> Build system -> New build system

type this:

```
{
"cmd": ["gnome-terminal -e 'bash -c \"python3 -u $file;echo;echo Press ENTER to exit; read line\"'"],"shell": true
}
```

and save it as python3.sublime-build

After that I quit sublime and relaunch it. I open a python file, then select

Tools -> Build system -> python3, and

Tools  -> Build

**A terminal window should appear but instead, nothing happens.**

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

could you go to Tools -> Build System -> new build system

paste the following in the window that open

```
{
   "path": "/usr/local/bin",
   "cmd": ["python3", "-u", "$file"],
   "file_regex": "^[ ]*File \"(...*?)\", line ([0-9]*)",
   "selector": "source.python"
}
```

then save it as pybuild.sublime-build for example and go to 
then go Tools -> Build System -> whatever name you chose
then Ctrl+B on whatever python file you want to run , this worked like a charm for me on Manjaro .

Comment: Sorry, I didn't work. A message _[Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'python3'_ appeared.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. I just had missed to install *gnome-terminal*. After installation, it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

The code provided by ImsoFancy doesnt work for me.
I have to change the line where it indicates the binary file:

```
"path": "/usr/bin",
```

And now it works. Tested on LinuxMint 18.2